# Error handelling for JPA EntityManager find(), remove(), persist() methods

Tags: jpa, find, entitymanager, persist

I am learning `JPA` using `EclipseLink`.
I searched a lot but did not found any answer.

My Question is when we use `EntityManager` `find()`, `remove()`, `persist()` methods how can we be sure that those methods worked as they are suppose to be.

For example if `persist()` persisted a row, if the insert did not happen for any reason will it return any error.

Similarly if `find()` has not found any data in database or `remove()` did not found the row to remove or did not removed because of constraints.

How can we handle these scenarios using exception handling?

Comment: you catch PersistenceException from remove/persist, and check the return from find ... as per their javadocs

Answer (score 0):

Typical use-case is to run those methods in try/catch block where you:

1. Open transaction
2. run your code
3. commit transaction
4. rollback transaction if Exception was thrown in the code.

As Neil already mentioned, any problem with EclipseLink methods will be seen as an Exception (PersistenceException in this case, but I will simply catch common Exception or even Throwable because not just persistence issue may happen and you can always rethrow them to upper layers of code after transaction is handled properly).

Here is nice [NetBeans sample](https://netbeans.org/projects/samples/sources/samples-source-code/content/samples/javaee/ConsultingAgency/consultingagencysolution/consultingagencysolution/ConsultingAgency/src/java/jpa/controllers/AddressJpaController.java?rev=32).